# How to receive array using AJAX which calls PHP script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

So basically what I'm doing is auto filling a textbox using AJAX to grab information from a PHP script that calls a C function.

This is what I've found in theory: *(Assuming receiving only one value)*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setInterval(function(){
        var ajaxurl = 'php/portserverclient.php',
        $.post(ajaxurl, NULL, function (response) {
            $('#v1').val(response); 
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

Now, if this works, which I believe it will. If I receive an array of values, then the input inside of function cannot be response, correct? So what would I have to change it to make it an array?

Just to be clear, my PHP script is using `echo` to output its information. I'd rather output in such a more "standard" manner as in V1 = 120, V2 = 120, etc. but PHP is new to me and that I am currently researching. Thank you.

**EDIT:**
**Just to make it clearer**

Would something like this work?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setInterval(function(){
        var ajaxurl = 'php/portserverclient.php',
        $.post(ajaxurl, NULL, function (response[]) {
            $('#v1').val(response[0]);
            $('#v2').val(response[1]);
            $('#v3').val(response[2]);
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: If you are using `echo`, the response is a `string`...

Comment: can you point me into the right direction into what to search to turn the response into an array please?

Comment: Sure... I'm finished editing my answer... Try it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you `echo` on PHP side, the response just can be a string.
But if that string if formed as a valid JSON, you will be able to use it like you wish.

So on PHP side, make sure the json format is valid:

```
$array = [120,340,800];

echo json_encode($array);
```

Then in JS... You received a string... You have to parse it to make it an array.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  window.setInterval(function(){
      var ajaxurl = 'php/portserverclient.php',
      $.post(ajaxurl, NULL, function (response[]) {
          var responseArray = JSON.parse(response);
          $('#v1').val(responseArray[0]);
          $('#v2').val(responseArray[1]);
          $('#v3').val(responseArray[2]);
      });
  }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the OP update, you could try something like this to map each item of the array up to its corresponding text box you could do.

```
    $.post(ajaxurl, NULL, function (response) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            $("#v" + (i + 1)).val(response[i]);
        }
    });
```

This would map each index of the array returned from the JSON endpoint, to a corresponding text box.

If the JSON being returned from your endpoint is a valid JSON array, your response variable should already be an array!

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the quick response. I edited the OP to make it a little clearer, I have multiple textboxes. V1, V2, V3, etc that I'd like to file. I guess a clearer way of asking what I'm trying to achieve is, how would i turn `response` inside the `.post` function into an array?

Comment: See my update and let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (for me) to communicate between javascript and PHP is JSON.
So your PHP script have to generate an answer in this format.

PHP code

```
// At the top of your PHP script add this
// that will tell to your browser to read the response as JSON
header('Content-Type    : application/json', true); 
// Do your logic to generate a PHP array
echo json_encode($yourArray);
```

HTML code

```
<div class="someClass"></div>
```

Javascript code

```
var container = $('.someClass');
$.post(ajaxurl, NULL, function (response) {
    console.log(response); // for debuging
    for (let i = 0; i <= response.length; i++) {
        let myItem = response[i];
        container.append('<p>' + item + '</p>');
    }
});
```

It's cleanest to generate dynamically the p elements because you don't know how many results your PHP file will return you.

I'm not sure of the javascript code, you maybe will received a json string that you have to transform to a Javascript Array

Before link you javascript to php script, try some call with postman (or others http client) to ensure that your 'webservice' is working as excepted

Answer (score 0):

Send your array as json:

```
echo json_encode(array($value1, $value2, $value3));
```

JS

```
$.post(ajaxurl, NULL, function (response) {
     // selectors in same index order as response array
     $('#v1, #v2, #v3').val(function(i){
       return response[i];
     });         
},'json');
```